# Regexp - joining multiple lines not starting with dash

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have lines that look like this:

```
- test 1
  test test test
  test test test
  test test test
- test2
- test3
  test test t
  test test test
- test 4
  test test test
- test5
```

I am looking for a regexp to convert them into this:

```
- test 1
  test test test test test test test test test
- test2
- test3
  test test t test test test
- test 4
  test test test
- test5
```

That is to remove all new line after each line that does not begin with `\s*?\-` and that does not precede a line that begins with `\s*?\-`

Comment: What is your regex flavor / tool ?

Comment: I am good enough with perl like... I use https://regex101.com/ for this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
^(\h*[^-\s].*)\R(?!-)
```

and replace with `$1`

- [`^`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches line start
- `(\h*[^-\s].*)` first [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) captures: Any amount of h-space followed by a character, that is [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `-` or `\s` whitespace, followed by any amount of any characters
- `\R(?!-)` newline sequence that's [not followed by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) a hyphen

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TLGjry/2/)

For joining parts by just one space [see this version](https://regex101.com/r/TLGjry/3) and replace with `$1`  (a bit less efficient).

Comment: ++ This is clever but it will also merge 2 lines without header lines e.g. `"..foo\n..bar\n"` (replace `.` with space)

Comment: @anubhava right, depends on input. was relying on sample input =)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in Perl/PCRE/Java etc:

Search regex:

```
(^-[^\n]*\n\h+|(?!^)\G)([^\n]*)\n(?!-)\h+
```

Replacement:

```
"$1$2 "
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eo4iBj/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(^-[^\n]*\n\h+|(?!^)\G)`: Group #1 to capture a line starting with `-` until end of line character followed 1+ spaces on next line. `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `([^\n]*)`: Match a line of 0 or more non-newline characters. Capture this in group #2
- `\n(?!-)`: Match newline if not followed by `-`
- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces

Comment: It does work on the demo but it does not work here: https://regex101.com/r/bm4094/2

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'if(/^-/){if($buffer){print" $buffer";print"\n"if/^-/}print;$buffer=""}else{chomp;$buffer.=s/^ +/ /r}END{print" $buffer\n"if$buffer}'
```

or, more readably

```
perl -ne 'if (/^-/) {
              if ($buffer) {
                  print " $buffer";
                  print "\n" if /^-/;
              }
              print;
              $buffer = "";
          } else {
              chomp;
              $buffer .= s/^ +/ /r;
          }
          END { print " $buffer\n" if $buffer }'
```